# Trying to add 4 years to the existing Fiscal Yr and I am wring as add_months(a.FY,48).FY is in format YYYY

Tags: sql

Trying to add 4 years to the existing Fiscal Yr and I am wring as add_months(a.FY,48).
Fiscal Yr is in format YYYY .Getting the "Literal Does not match" Error

select add_months(a.FY,48) from table_a a
"Literal Does not match"

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Explain what fiscal year means in your context.

Comment: `a.FY` should be a date, if its an integer than do `+4`

Comment: It is a char with only 4 chars's which is YYYY and +4 did not work either